# Issues using FancyBox 2.1.5 after upgrading APEX 4.2 to 5.0.3

Tags: fancybox, apex

Please help us get FancyBox working with APEX V5.0.3

Our migration to APEX V5.0.3 was going smoothly, we kept the V4.2 production server and loaded v5.0.3 to another pre-prod glassfish server.  All of our applications were working fine on the PRE-PROD box until we tested the application that uses FancyBox.

None of the FancyBox features appear to work.  The images display inline but there are no errors and the images do not appear to be linked to FancyBox or anything else.

The FancyBox folder JS is stored in the same place as they were on the Prod Server.  BeyondCompare verifies The files on both servers are the same (binary comparison).

```
\\Pre-ProdServer\e$\apex_5.0.3_en\apex\images 
\\Prod_Server001\e$\apex_4_2_2\apex\images
```

Any suggestions from anyone?

Comment: Is FancyBox compatible with APEX V5x?

Comment: Check your console errors, what do they say?

Comment: There were no console errors

Comment: Thanks but there were no console errors.  When I explored the fancy box elements the <img src> tag is defined but the <a href> tag was missing.  The developer discovered the error and was able to correct the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The developer was following the advice of fac586 from the this link https://community.oracle.com/message/13815177#13815177.

Our code for using fancybox has to be updated to work in Apex V5.

1st the fancybox file had to be uploaded into a shared component.
2nd The JavaScript in the dynamic actions had to be updated
and 3rd the page template had to be updated as well.